# How to I make a navigation-based app?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Yes, I know, most of you are thinking I'm an idiot, butt (kidding) I'm not. I've been searching everywhere for something on how to fully make a navigation-based iphone app, but all I've found is how to set up table views or navigation controllers. I haven't found anything on how to create a data model (something simple from arrays and dictionaries, SQLite and CoreData are a bit out of my scope) or navigate it. Does anyone know of any tutorials or anything like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key phrase you're looking for is a 'drill down' pattern.

Apple has a great example (with full sample application) of a drill-down application with a basic data controller:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

The Stanford iPhone Development Course provides good information on how to set-up a navigation based app. Specifically, lectures 7 - 9 deal with the topics you were interested in. You can find the lectures on iTunes U. The course assignments and handouts are also available on the [course website](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-winter).